# Object.defineProperty does nothing in constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js

I've recently restructured my three.js project and I started to encounter a problem where every object seems to be rendered with the exact same geometry and material. I tracked the problem to this constructor in the debugger:

```
function Geometry() {
    Object.defineProperty( this, 'id', { value: GeometryIdCount() } );
    this.uuid = exports.Math.generateUUID();
    ...
```

Chrome shows no properties on the `this` object after the `Object.defineProperty`, and `id` comes back as `undefined` when things try to use it later. However, when I debug older projects I've made using three.js, the `id` is defined on `this` in the debugger after the call.

What could cause `Object.defineProperty` to do nothing?  The most likely culprit is that I've switched from using node.js `require` calls from Javascript to include three to ES6 `import` calls from Typescript with a TS compiler, but it's not clear to me why that would have this effect on this constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Just saying that "`id` comes back as undefined" doesn't necessarily mean that `Object.defineProperty` did nothing, although I do understand that you looked at the properties of `this` directly after the `Object.defineProperty` call, and I can't explain that. If `GeometryIdCount()` returns undefined, then that would explain why the value is `undefined` later. Have you verified that the property itself is undefined, rather than the property value, after the constructor completes?

It may be like using the word "utilize" instead of "use", or maybe Typescript, ES6 or three.js require it, but why don't you instead write:

```
this.id = GeometryIdCount();
```

This will still assign unknown to `this.id` if the function returns undefined, however.

**Update:**
Your question got me to research [exactly what Object.defineProperty does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), and it was surprising and very informative. When I worked with WebGL, I didn't use three.js, so I incorrectly assumed that Geometry was a function that you wrote.

When you call Object.defineProperty in the way that you describe, (setting the 3rd argument to an Object with only the "value" property) it sets the writable, configurable and enumerable properties, which all Object properties have, to false. The statement `this.id = GeometryIdCount()`, on the other hand, will set those 3 properties to true. The author of three.js apparently wanted to assign a unique key to each Geometry object and make it so the user can't change its value. I didn't look for other reasons.

I recommend that you make a copy of your project and whittle out anything that you want to keep secret, (if you want to post it here) and get rid of as much distracting code as you can, to make it easier to determine what is causing the problem. You know, stop removing code when you can no longer reproduce this bad behavior where the id property is not created or it is undefined. I made a small program and tried to guess how to repro the problem, doing bad things like `Geometry.prototype.id = undefined` before calling var `g = Geometry(...)`, (without the new keyword) but was unable to reproduce the problem. I didn't go so far as to try to override the behavior of `GeometryIdCount`, or prevent the creation of the `id` property. That seems like intentional sabotage, and I doubt you suspect that in your case.

Comment: I stepped into `GeometryIdCount` and it appeared to be returning a valid integer.  I did in fact change the code to what you wrote, and it works.  That requires me to change threejs source, though, so I'll have to do it again if I update, and it doesn't solve the mystery.